# Is the usage "multiple logistic regression analysis" correct?

Tags: word-usage, phrasing, scientific-language

I encountered a manuscript where the author writes:

> Risk associations for metabolic syndrome and diabetes were analyzed using multiple logistic regression analyses..."

In this case, is the usage *regression analyses* correct? Isn't the word multiple logistic regression self-sufficient? I felt it was inaccurate to use analyzed twice in the same sentence.

Comment: You could try replacing the initial "analyzed" with a synonym, e.g. "were evaluated using multiple logistic regression analyses..."

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not in a standard register and is a better fit on say Mathematics.SE. The issue about whether to use two related lexemes so close together in a sentence is essentially an opinion-based matter.

Answer (score 1):

A correct parsing of this phrase would be:

> multiple (Logistic Regression) analyses

[Logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression#:%7E:text=Logistic%20regression%20is%20a%20statistical,a%20form%20of%20binary%20regression) is a separate term and is a statistical model. The writer is doing multiple analyses, all of which use logistic regression.

At its core, the sentence is:

> Risk associations ... were analyzed using multiple ... analyses

So the associations *were analyzed* using *multiple analyses*. This seems grammatically and syntactically correct.

Comment: Downvoter, would you please explain how I might make this a better answer?